# SVG text grows and overflows on mobile browser

Tags: css, svg

I have a basic SVG element that displays curved text. Although I use a web safe font and relative units in style, the text somehow grows and overflows on mobile browser. I use Chrome 120 both on desktop and Android. I tried other fonts, MS Edge, setting 1rem/16px font-size on root element, they did not help. Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

| Desktop | Mobile |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Desktop] | [image] |

Here's the page I use to test:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
    <defs>
      <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap');
      </style>
      <path id="yz" d="M61.92190299775521,240 A178.0780970022448,178.0780970022448 0 0 1 418.0780970022448,240"></path>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <text style="font-family: 'PT Serif', serif; font-size: 6.9ex; white-space: pre; letter-spacing: -0.05ex;">
      <textPath href="#yz"> LOREM  IPSUM  DOLOR</textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
```

Here's a live version of the page:
https://gold-gertie-8.tiiny.site/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`white-space` property applied to svg text is still inconsistently supported across major browsers.

For a more predictable rendering, try to achieve the layout via SVG `startOffset`  and CSS `word-spacing`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
  <defs>
    <style>
      /*
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap');
        */
      /* latin */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'PT Serif';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptserif/v18/EJRSQgYoZZY2vCFuvAnt66qSVys.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
    </style>
    <path id="yz" d="M61.9 240a178.1 178.1 0 0 1 356.2 0"></path>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />

  <text style="font-family: 'PT Serif', serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 3.1em; letter-spacing: -0.022em; word-spacing:0.2em">
    <textPath startOffset="2.1%" href="#yz">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

As commented by @Danny '365CSI' Engelman you can also center text on a `<textPath>` by adding:

- `text-anchor:midde` for center alignment
- `startOffset=50%` or alternatively specifying a [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) and a absolute value for the startOffset such as 5 - based on a PathLength of 10.

However you might need to tweak the startoffset manually to get the visually and typographically  most appealing alignment.

```html
<h3>Text align center (startOffset: 50%)</h3>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
  <defs>
    <style>
      /*
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap');
        */
      /* latin */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'PT Serif';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptserif/v18/EJRSQgYoZZY2vCFuvAnt66qSVys.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
    </style>
    <path id="yz" d="M61.9 240a178.1 178.1 0 0 1 356.2 0"></path>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />

  <text style="font-family: 'PT Serif', serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 3.1em; letter-spacing: -0.022em; word-spacing:0.2em">
    <textPath startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" href="#yz">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>

<h3>Text align center (pathLength:10; startOffset:5)</h3>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
  <defs>
    <style>
      /*
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap');
        */
      /* latin */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'PT Serif';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptserif/v18/EJRSQgYoZZY2vCFuvAnt66qSVys.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
    </style>
    <path id="textPath2" d="M61.9 240a178.1 178.1 0 0 1 356.2 0" pathLength="10"></path>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />

  <text style="font-family: 'PT Serif', serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 3.1em; letter-spacing: -0.022em; word-spacing:0.2em">
    <textPath startOffset="5" text-anchor="middle" href="#textPath2">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

You may also prefer `em` or better `px` units at least for svg text. Older browsers  might use slightly different calculations and roundings for the relative `ex` unit.

Although (usually negligible) you may also force a specific font file by embedding the `@font-face` rule directly. Google fonts applies a lot of browser sniffing - thus an iOS safari will retrieve a slightly different font version.

Comment: What should I look to determine the support level of CSS (or SVG, or javascript, etc) in a browser? They both said version 120 for the Chrome I used, but apparently that number is not definitive.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no ultimate way or source (like caniuse) when it comes to CSS properties applied to svg text elements. (Whitespace is supported flawlessly for HTML elements since ages) Besides, svg's text elements are always good for a surprise ... sometimes it's just related to browser bugs or different implementations due to sometimes ambiguous  specs. Probably the best resource are related SO posts. Sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: It might also help to center the text around the top point of the arc, with ``pathLength`` and ``align``, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291003/add-text-to-svg-path-dynamically/67297788#67297788

Comment: @herrstrietzel How many digits after decimal point is significant in SVG? I see you rounded them up to one digit in your answer, my numbers are calculated by Javascript and I left them as they are, but would consider rounding if that many digits are insignificant.

Comment: @Tekins it depends: rule of thumb if your path is ~ 500x500 units you might even use integers without a significant loss in quality. The smaller your path the more decimals you need. Usually 3 decimals are enough. See also ["How to reduce quality or improve rendering performance of SVG File?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703312/how-to-reduce-quality-or-improve-rendering-performance-of-svg-file/75709073#75709073) In your case it doesn't really matter since the svg is overall quite compact. It is rather a way to minify your markup

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman: Thanks I've updated the answer. Frankly I've never experienced a case where `startOffset=50%` didn't work as well. But it's save to say the whole svg text compositing concept needs a major overhaul –  I'm not too confident that we'll ever get proper multiline/text wrapping capabilities ;(